# Use VBA to send a command to RStudio's Console

Tags: r, vba, rstudio

I want to do these steps in a macro:

1. Open Rstudio if it's not open yet.
2. Activate Rstudio
3. Put a command into the Rstudio's console.
4. Hit enter, telling Rstudio to run the given command.

I can do (1) and I can theoretically do (3) with Sendkeys if I can do (2), but (2) isn't working.

These two lines are the basic idea but using notepad instead:

```
PID = Shell("C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus)
SendKeys "source('C:/Users/Athena/Documents/helloworld.r')", True
```

Here a step (2) isn't even necessary since VBA sends the string in sendkeys directly into notepad like how I want. But if I try the same code with RStudio, the string gets pasted into the VBA code instead (or into the excel book if I used a button to activate the macro).

So in my mind, I want to force VBA to put focus on RStudio, then sendkeys will work as intended, and then I can do (4) somehow, telling RStudio to run the code I sent it.

Comment: Knowing enough about VBA and R, I think this would be horrible to try to maintain. What is your ultimate goal? Perhaps there's a better way to resolve your *need* vice in this manner.

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-run-r-from-the-task-scheduler/

Comment: Don't you need to prefix `SendKeys` with an `Application` object that's supposed to receive the keys?

Comment: I'm aware that I can send the code directly to Rscript and it'll run the code, but the issue is I need it in RStudio so the created lists continue existing and can be viewed and analyzed. Running the code in Rscript directly allows me to send the data to an excel/cvs file, but that adds minutes to the compute time and isn't as easy to analyze.

I don't know the intricacies of making SendKeys work, is there something I'm missing here to make it work with RStudio?